# How to change an input to be enabled using React JS

Tags: reactjs

```
function EditServiceDetails(props) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(props.item.name);
    const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState('disabled');
    const [read, setRead] = useState(true);

    const changeName = (e) => {
        setName({ name: e.target.value });
    };

    const edit = () => {
        console.log("HI")
        setRead({ read: false });
        setEnabled({ enabled: '' });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='edit' onClick={edit}>Edit</div>
            <br />
                <label htmlFor='editSName'> Name :</label>
                <input type='text' id='editSName' name='editSName' defaultValue={name} onChange={changeName} readOnly={read} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to enable the input when user clicked "Edit", I used "read" and "enabled" hooks for that as above.. but when I click Edit the input stills disabled, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need update `setRead({ read: false });` become `setRead(false);`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `disabled` attribute of the input element.

Then you can have a value in your state, but instead of calling it `enabled`, you could call it `disabled` and use a boolean for this value and set it to `true`.

The `disabled` attribute in your input element is then dictated by this value.  `<input type='text' id='editSName' name='editSName' defaultValue={name} onChange={changeName} disabled={disabled} />`

Inside `edit()` function you then set the state:

`setDisabled(false)`